# Extremum of function on l1

Tags: functional-analysis

How to prove that $f: l_1 \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t.
$$f((x_n)_{n \in N})= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{n} x_{n}^{2}+ x_{n}^{3})$$ is a function of class $C^{\infty}$ and $f'(0)=0$ and $f''(0)(h,h)>0$ for $h\in l_1 \setminus \{0 \}$ but $f$ has no extremum at $0$

Let $x=((x_n)_{n \in N}) $ and $h=((h_n)_{n \in N}) $
I calculate the Frechet derivative
$f(x+h)-f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[ (\frac{1}{n} x_{n}^{2}+ h_{n}^{2}) +x_{n}^{3}+3 x_{n}h_{n}^{2}+h_{n}^{3} \right]+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{2}{n} x_{n}h_{n}+3 x_{n}^{2}h_{n}) $
I think that,
$$f'(x)h=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{2}{n} x_{n}h_{n}+3 x_{n}^{2}h_{n})$$ because it is linear and continuous.
$$\lim_{h \to (0,0, \ldots)} \frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)h|}{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  |h_{n}|}=\lim_{h \to (0,0, \ldots)} \frac{|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{1}{n}h_{n}^{2}) + 3 x_{n}h_{n}^{2}+h_{n}^{3} \right]|}{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  |h_{n}|}= \lim_{h \to (0,0, \ldots)} |\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  (\frac{1}{n}h_{n} + 3 x_{n}h_{n}+h_{n}^{2})|=0 $$ How to calculate the second derivative?

Comment: Why do you still have the terms $x_n^2/n$ and $x_n^3$ in $f(x+h)-f(x)$?  Could this be the source of your problem?

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the second derivivative, calculate the difference quotient
$$
\lim_{t\searrow0}{f'(x+th_2)h_1 - f'(x)h_1}t
$$
for arbitrary $h_1,h_2\in l^1$. You will find the second order directional derivative
$$
f''(x)(h_1,h_2)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n h_{1,n}h_{2,n} + 6x_n h_{1,n}h_{2,n}.
$$
Similarly to your reasoning to prove that $f'$ is the Frechet derivative of $f$, you can now prove that $f''$ is the Frechet derivative of $f'$.

In addition, you see that the mapping $x\mapsto f''(x)$ is affine linear, hence $C^\infty$.

Now it is clear that $f'(0)=0$ and $f''(0)(h,h)>0$ for all $h\ne 0$.

To see that $0$ is not a local extremum, calculate $f(te_n)$ for $t>0$ and $e_n$ being the unit vector in $l^1$:
$$
f(te_n) = \frac1n t^2 + t^3 \to t^3 \text{ for } n\to\infty.
$$
Thus you find in any neighborhood of $0$ points, where $f$ is positive and negative, hence $0$ cannot be an extreme point.